# Editable Rich text box

Tags: c#, textbox

Please Do any one know a free rich text box in C# like the one used in Microsoft Encarta, such that when i write x^2 it makes the 2 up the x with smaller font (like sup in HTML). 
Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

The possibility to make text superscript or subscript is built-in in the richtextbox: see this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectioncharoffset.aspx).

Of course the base richtextbox does not do it "automatically", but you might try replacing text as the user types...

**EDIT**: If I understand correctly, you don't need just subscript and superscript capabilities, but a full **equation editor**. I don't have any direct experience with something like that, but just googling for ".net equation editor" yields some interesting results, like this [equation editor in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/MathEquationEditor08292005104727AM/MathEquationEditor.aspx). Give it a try... I'm afraid that it won't be easy to find something that 1) does exactly what you need 2) is easy to use and 3) is free, but I wish you all the best luck :)

Comment: Thanks that is very nice, but the problem is it needs a lot of work because i also want the fragment line, the sqrt and all symbols. Do you know a one that is complete to use it directly because i do not have time to program these details.
Thanks very much for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know encarta do. But if you want some components for edit html try find:

http://www.fckeditor.net/

http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Editors/ (serach for a new editor control, can edit html)

Comment: I am sorry but perhaps i do not explained it clearly. I want the component for windows application (actually WPF) but i gave the html as an example. What i want is something similar to word 2007 when you write  insert equations.

Comment: Actually i was wrong when i said Microsoft Encarta, I meant Microsoft Math which comes with Encarta.